# How to make Spring Data Neo4j ignore connection check when the project starts?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring-Data-Neo4j in my SpringBoot project. However, IntelliJ Idea  is always giving below error message when neo4j console is not running behind:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
```

I know the reason for the error. Cause I didn't start the database. How to avoid error occurs when the database is not running.

Below is my codes:

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.inspur.neo4j.domain")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.inspur.neo4j.repositories")
public class DataGraphApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DataGraphApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9012
spring:
  data:
    neo4j:
      uri: bolt://localhost
      username: neo4j
      password: Passw0rd
```

Is there any way to avoid error occurs when the database is not running?

Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, I found the answer on the official [website](https://neo4j.com/developer/java-driver-spring-boot-starter/). We can add below property to springboot `application.yml` file.

```
management.health.neo4j.enabled
```

The complete configuration is as follows：

```
server:
  port: 9012
spring:
  data:
    neo4j:
      uri: bolt://localhost
      username: neo4j
      password: Passw0rd
management:
    neo4j:
      enabled: false
```

Finally, IntelliJ Idea never show error message when neo4j console is not running behind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can disable this
Add this to your main class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to enable or disable neo4j in an configuration file?

Comment: I added that to the main class: 

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.inspur.neo4j.domain")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.inspur.neo4j.repositories")
public class DataGraphApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DataGraphApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```
It seems not work.